# Solving the matrix equation $B = ABA^T + C$ for $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I have the equation 
$$B = ABA^T + C$$
where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all square matrices. For simplicity, we can assume anything we want to be invertible is invertible.

I would like to be able to solve for $B$ in terms of just $A$ and $C$, but I can't see any way to simplify this. The only thing I can think to do is to move all the $B$ terms to the same side and try to left-multiply and/or right-multiply by a suitable matrix to isolate $B$, but I haven't been successful at this. Does anyone have any ideas as to how (and if) we can isolate $B$ in this expression somehow?

Comment: Note that this is an instance of the [discrete-time Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n$ be the common size of all square matrices. Using the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), we have
$$
B = ABA^T + C \implies\\
B - ABA^T = C \implies\\
\operatorname{vec}(B) - (A \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B) = \operatorname{vec}(C) \implies\\
(I - A \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B) = \operatorname{vec}(C) \implies\\
\operatorname{vec}(B) = (I - A \otimes A)^{-1}\operatorname{vec}(C).
$$
Here, $I$ denotes the $n^2 \times n^2$ identity matrix, and $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

As it turns out, the matrix $(I - A \otimes A)$ is invertible (which means that our equation will necessarily have a unique solution) if and only if there is no $\lambda$ for which both $\lambda$ and $1/\lambda$ are eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Doesn't the second dot point implies the first?

Comment: @u good point ${}$

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the vectorization operator - thanks so much for your insight!